# Conditional expectation when throwing two dice

Tags: probability-distributions

I throw two dice.  The random variable X gives the result of the first die and the random variable Y gives the result of the sum of the two dice.  What is the value of E(Y!X)?

Comment: What does $Y!X$ mean?

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini: I was assuming it meant conditional expectation as in $E[Y|X]$.

Comment: But don't you need an event on the right hand side of $|$?

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini: It is conditioned by the $\sigma$-field generated by $X$ as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Formal_definition

Answer (score 2):

Let $D_1,D_2$ be the value of each throw. Assume the throws are fair and independent.

Then $E[D_1+D_2|D_1] = E[D_1|D_1]+E[D_2|D_1] = D_1+E[D_2] = D_1+{7 \over 2}$.

In terms of the question variables, $E[Y|X] = X+ {7 \over 2} $.

Comment: And what if, in the same example, E((Y!X=3)?

Comment: @user118601: $E[Y|X=3] = 3 + {7 \over 2}$.